# Is servlet is not in use now a days?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have read the following about JSP [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482852/is-jsp-really-considered-deprecated)

But there is no discussion about servlet technology.

My Question is  "Are servlets being used today, or are they deprecated ?"
Actually I need a update . :)

Comment: Coding your presentation logic into servlets directly has been "deprecated" for a very long time. There are frameworks you should be using instead, and many of them have been implemented using servlets. So to sum it up: don't use them unless you're writing a framework.

Comment: Better suited for programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet container!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not deprecated. They are still releasing new features on the latest Servlet (like async Servlet).

And many of the Java web frameworks are building on top the the Servlet technology. 
But it might be right that less people are using it directly since it is so easy to use one of the Java web frameworks (which built on top on Servlet).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Servlet(s) continue to be used. Even if you never write one, every [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) (per the linked Wikipedia article) is one.

> JSPs are translated into servlets at runtime